# Complete table not visible in Case feed when case is created using email to case

Tags: case, email2case

I have a requirement where I need to create an email to case. The mail consists of table having a large number of rows and columns. However, when I send the mail, the case is created. When I look in the case feed, the table that I sent is truncated to few rows and the whole data that is sent is not populated.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the text body greater than 5000 characters?

If so you are hitting the max character limit for chatter.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfV8UAJ/increase-the-chatter-feed-character-limit

Sounds like the users are going to need to click into the email to get the full data.

Another option is to try to create some type of automation that texts your text and populates it to a rich text field.

Not really sure what the use case is for wanting to see a very large email in the case feed.  This isn't what chatter is designed to do..

Comment: Thanks Benjamin!